# Are questions for song identification on topic?

Tags: discussion, topics

I have a song from a game for which I believe the tune is an old folk song. I'd like some help figuring it out what the name of the folk song is, but I'm not sure (from the active questions) if that sort of thing would be on topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - from https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, you can see that "identifying a song, style/genre, instrument/equipment, technique, chord progression, etc." is off topic.

However the good news is that such questions *are* on topic on [musicfans.stackexchange.com](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) (as long as they are asked with sufficient detail that an identification might be possible).